# Inserting variable into sed command in bash script

Tags: bash, sed, regex

I have text file similar to this:

```
Some-text
Keyword
Some-text
Some-text
Keyword
Some-text
Keyword
Keyword
```

I want to replace every "Keyword" with "number.extension" where number is 1 at first keyword match, 2 at second keyword match etc.

I know that I should use bash loop combined with sed (sed 's:Keyword:Number:g'), but I am not sure how to insert variable for number in that sed command.

As this is HTML file, there can be blank lines or any text beetween those "Keywords".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
perl -pe '$n++ if /Some-text/;s/Keyword/SomeText '\''$n'\''/'
```

For more complicated replacements (e.g. where maths is involved), more advanced scripting language might be more suitable.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not load any file and (as far as I can see) this is very important. Could you explain how it is supposed to work?

Comment: @Rafal: Just add the file path as the last argument, or redirect (pipe) it to the script. The `-p` switch loads the file automatically.

Comment: Your orginal script does nothing with my file. I guess that I have not been clear about what I need. When I replace "Some-text" with ".*?" and second with "\1" reference it does change keyword to number of line. I have modified it, to do exactly what I need: 'perl -pe '$n++ if /MYLONGKEYWORD/; s/MYLONGKEYWORD/$n/' example-input.html'. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Edited : You may use the variable in sed as follows,

```
count=1
extension=".jpg"
cp yourfile tempfile
for (( i=1; i<=`wc yourfile | awk '{ print $1 }'`; i++))
do

#for (( j=1; j<=`sed -n ''"$i"' p' yourfile | wc | awk '{ print $2 }'`; j++))
#do
        sed -i ''"$i"' s/[a-zA-Z0-9]*[Kk][Ee][Yy][Ww][Oo][Rr][Dd]/'"$count$extension"'/1' yourfile
        diff yourfile tempfile
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
        then    
        count=$(expr $count + 1)
        cp yourfile tempfile
        fi  
#done
done
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, it does not do what I neeed. I have updated question to be more clear. This text beetween keywords might be very different. I just want to replace every occurence of my keyword with growing number and file extension. Example HTML files here https://www.dropbox.com/s/qinykn154nhjymu/example.zip